# Best way to filter both Vertically and Horizontally?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large data set which contains users and the groups they belong too (they can be in many groups). I currently have 265 users and 94 groups. I'd like to find the best way to display this information. Right now I have a very large spreedsheet that shows me this information, but I can only filter the groups (column) to find out which users are in that group. Ideally, It would be great to also be able to filter the users to find all the groups on user belongs too.

Here's a demo of what my sheet looks like:
[image]

Transposing won't work with 265 users and I'd rather not have two spreadsheets with the same information. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: why 265 users will not work?? are you using Excel 2003??

Comment: Well technically it will work but scrolling horizontally to look through 256 names isn't the best option really. Plus I'd like not to have to use two tables with the same data.

Comment: @Batman the easiest way to display the table in a transposed way would be to use a `pivot table`. however if you still would like to transpose this, try writing some VBA then we will help make it work

Comment: unpivot the data then pivot it again using the desired filters (http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel) to unpiviot.

Comment: @mehow, I'll look around online for something similar because I dont know VBA

Comment: @Batman you dont need to know any VBA to use a [pivot table - click here for a tutorial](http://spreadsheets.about.com/b/2012/06/01/excel-2007-pivot-table-tutorial-2.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your data in one table with two columns, "User Name" and "Group Name", and one record for each group that each user belongs to.  For example, the first few rows might be:

```
User Name      Group Name
User 1         Group 1
User 1         Group 5
User 2         Group 5
User 2         Group 6
```

You can filter this table on "User Name" to see what groups a specific user belongs to, or on "Group Name" to see what users belong to a specific group.

If you want to see your table in a "matrix" form, create a pivot table based on the table.

As a one-time exercise to convert your data from its current format to the new format, you might:

1. Create a new worksheet.
2. In the new worksheet, enter the following column headings in the first row of columns A through F, respectively:  **Cell Number**, **Row Number**, **Column Number**, **Cell Value**, **User Name**, and **Group Name**.
3. In the new worksheet, enter the following formulas: `=ROW()-1` in cell A2, `=INT((A2-1)/94)+1` in cell B2, `=MOD(A2-1,94)+1` in cell C2, `=INDEX('Your Existing Data'!$E$2:$CT$266,B2,C2)` in cell D2, `=INDEX('Your Existing Data'!$A$2:$A$266,B2,1)` in cell E2, and `=INDEX('Your Existing Data'!$E$1:$CT$1,1,C2)` in cell F2.  This assumes that your existing data is in a worksheet named "Your Existing Data" and laid out as shown in the image referenced in your comment.
4. Copy the formulas down to row 24911 (265 * 94 + 1).
5. Copy the formulas and paste over them with their values.
6. Use a filter to delete the rows that don't have an X in the **Cell Value** column.
7. Delete columns A through D.

If you want, you can add also formulas to the new worksheet to look up the first name, last name, and e-mail from your existing data based on the full name.

Comment: Doing this will take far too long. I have 264 users and 94 groups. Doing it like you suggested isn't feasible.

Comment: I disagree.  I've added an explanation of how to do this to my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure which table you chose to base your formulas on, the red or the blue one?

Comment: This is what my sheet looks like right now. I'm trying to follow ur instructions but I'm having a hard time adjusting it. http://i.imgur.com/k0On2gG.png

Comment: Thanks for the image.  I had assumed the blue format.  I've revised my asnwer to suit the layout shown in the image.

Comment: is there a way to get the Full User name to show up in the User Name column, right now i'm only getting the first name. I've tried changing the reference in the E@ function to A2 instead of B2 but that didn't do it.

Comment: If the full name is in `'Your Existing Data'!$A$2:$A$266` then `=INDEX('Your Existing Data'!$A$2:$A$266,B2,1)` should give the full name in row number B2.  If it's not, double-check that you haven't missed a step, and if that doesn't reveal anything, post back with the formulas you have and the values you're getting in cells A2 through F2 on the new worksheet.

Comment: I looked up what this formulas did (I have no clue) and I just recreated the references by going to the tab and dragging to the needed fields. It's a little different from you formulas  because it just used the table names, for example: =INDEX(Table2[[#Headers],[ADMIN]:[Vistors ]],1,C2) Maybe that's why it wasn't working properly?

Comment: Also, I just learned (Because of you) that I can copy a formula and paste the value over that same cell. Sweet. I used to copy the values into a different cell and move it back over to the one with the formula. Now I realize how pointless that was.

Comment: Just one last thing, do you now of a way that may be better to display this information? Because right now it looks like the table you have above, so there's a lot of duplicates in the names which makes for a very long list.

Comment: I suggested you post another question describing how you want to display the data given how it's stored now and see what answers you get.